Multiprocessing Writing Over Input Parameters
I'm trying to run the executable file main.exe which accepts a parameter and runs the function fun in other_file.py. The function fun uses multiprocessing to perform some computationally intensive tasks. It seems like fun is run multiple times when main.exe is called, but the parameter of the function is altered after the first run. Here is a boiled down version of what I'm doing.
main.py:
import sys
import other_file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    other_file.mp.freeze_support()
    param = sys.argv[1]
    with open(r"check1.txt", 'w') as output:       
        output.write(param)  
    output.close()
    other_file.fun(param)

other_file.py:
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun(param): 
    with open(r"check2.txt", 'w') as output:       
        output.write(param)  
    output.close()
    # Stuff with multiprocessing below

I converted main.py to the executable main.exe using pyinstaller. When I try to run it via something like the code below check1.txt contains 'param_val' as expected. A few moments later check2.txt also contains 'param_val' as expected, but then yet another few moments later check2.txt is overwritten and now contains '--multiprocessing-fork'. My executable file then throws an error because '--multiprocessing-fork' isn't an acceptable input for fun.
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r"main.exe", 'param_val'])


I would expect that if the indentation were not as you have it here.  You're SURE that's how it looks?

@TimRoberts Above is an illustration and I don't see what the indentation problem is. In my code, I used tabs, so it's a little different than this.

What do you do in # Stuff with multiprocessing below? It should be caused by some codes in it.

@happy_code_egg I have a pandas array, and I'm doing a rolling calculation on each column. The multithreading breaks up the calculation based on the index, and I use the np.apply_along_axis to calculate the results for each column given the particular window. Mutithreading is done twice in # Stuff with multiprocessing below.

This sounds like the type of issue that freeze_support is explicitly supposed to fix. Is there a reason you import it from other_file instead of directly importing multiprocessing inside of main.py

@Aaron No, other than avoiding duplicate imports. I've done this elsewhere and it has worked fine, but this is more complicated. Do you think importing it in main.py would help?

duplicate imports within a given process are cached so there's no performance penalty. I Don't know exactly what's going on in this situation so I don't know it will solve the problem, but to me the direct import is cleaner (it shows readers that you're using the default freeze_support rather than a customized version from other_file).

@Aaron Sorry for being slow about getting back to you. I had some IDE problems, and ended up reinstalling everything. Anyway, I put mp in the main.py file and converted it to an executable. It made it past all the checks, but still hasn't finished, though it's super slow so that's not shocking (I want it to be an executable so I can run it at night). I think this problem has been resolved. Thank you for your help!

Just fyi, If all you need is an executable to be able to point something like task scheduler to; I tend to create my projects as a library using setuptools to define entrypoints. After installing the completed wheel, exe files for each entrypoint will be added to you python scripts folder. I mainly do this as frozen executables tend to get false positives by antivirus, to which I have no easy way to deal with (for corporate environment).
